# Angular 2 OnPush change detection for dynamic components

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have an Angular component that dynamically creates various other types of component inside itself. It binds its own properties to child component `@Input` properties via an `OnChanges` hook.

This binding works fine when the child component's change detection is set to Default. Then the new inputs are detected and the component template is updated.

However, it doesn't work when change detection is OnPush, then the change is not detected. I believe the change should be detected because a new immutable object, a string, is assigned to a component `@Input` property.

Here's a plunker to demonstrate:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0wHQghtww2HXVbC27bC1

How can I get this parent-to-dynamic-child property binding to work with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

Comment: For anyone interested, here's the related GitHub issue with more info about why OnPush change detection works differently for dynamic components - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14087

Comment: Is this issue fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As possible workaround for OnPush component would be using setter together with `cdRef.markForCheck()`:

**change-detection-onpush.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-detection-onpush',
  template: `
    <div>
      ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush: {{ message || '[blank]' }}
    </div>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChangeDetectionOnPushComponent implements IMyComponent {
  private _message: string;

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  set message(val: string) {
    this.cdRef.markForCheck();
    this._message = val;
  }

  get message() {
    return this._message;
  }
}
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NJRoUOvfrI8dQkWRoLcM?p=preview)**

Comment: Seems, Plunker not working, Would it be possible to move to working code to Stackblitz.

Comment: @Cegone Please look at this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/NJRoUOvfrI8dQkWRoLcM?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @Yurzui, It's working for me. Actually, I missed this part,  
set message(val: string) {
    this.cdRef.markForCheck();
    this._message = val;
  }
But, When we try for Dump Component, Is this fine?, because we need to inject ChangeDetectorRef in Constructor.

Comment: if many input variable available in ChangeDetectionOnPushComponent component, is i need to put markForCheck() in all input variable?

Answer (score 0):

Angular now has the `setInput()` method on `ComponentRef` https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#setInput

So, you can easily set your inputs from within the host component like so:

```
const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<MyDynamicComponent>(MyDynamicComponent);
componentRef.setInput('myInputName', 'myInputValue');
```

Using this method should automatically call `markForCheck()` without having to specify additional logic in the child components.